# access chrome password manager

Tags: google-chrome-extension, passwords

I am writing a chrome extension, and I want to find out if the built-in password manager has saved the password of a specific website.

I don't want to know the password, just to find out if there is one for this website.

do you have any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to interact with the password manager.

There may be very hacky ways of inspecting the loaded login form, but I don't think you're looking for those.

Comment: thanks for your answer, exactly this is not what I m looking for.

Comment: Anyway that would allow you to do this would be a pretty big security bug.  Password managers go to great lengths to prevent applications from accessing them.

Comment: @Brian It would be fine if it was a specific permission, maybe requiring additional user confirmation besides the install dialog. But there's simply no API.